# PHP Laravel 5.8 Auth Attempt always return false in PHP 72

Tags: php, laravel-5

Running the same code, request parameter and database on different machine specification resulting different behavior.

First one we ran on our sandbox server with specification bellow

> Centos 7
>   PHP 7.2
>   MySQL 5.7
>   Apache 2.4

returning always false even username and password are correct

```
{"status":"invalid email"}
```

Secondly, we ran same code, request parameter and database at our development server with specification bellow

> Centos 7
>   PHP 7.3
>   MySQL 8
>   Apache 2.4

**return always true indicate by redirect to another page**

Check our code bellow.

```
public function login(Request $request){

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){

        return redirect()->to('/location');
    }
```

It should be a simple and clean code. After digging on Internet, some article suggested using `bcrypt` so we have trying that solution and against, we got a different result.

What happened here? Does somebody has faced same issue as us?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using setPaswordAttribute on User Model?

Comment: No, we dont used

Comment: Maybe it helps I dont know why i encountered this issue, I fixed it with to find correct php version for laravel project, php version should be to match laravel